# Word 2016: Using StyleRef for Heading #s in Header differently

Tags: vba, styles, headers, microsoft-word-2016, field-codes

I have a document that requires the heading to contain the item number (level 3 heading) that is being *continued onto that page* from the previous page. Using the Field insert and StyleRef, I can make the heading show either the item that appears first or last on that page- but I can't make it reference the page before. Could a little bit of VBA do the trick? Anyone had to do this before?

Comment: See this posted [example document](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=4DE3A20A33EEA203!1284&app=Word) for a solution, entailing a rather painful use of SEQ fields.

Comment: Wow, @harrymc, that is phenomenal. Thank you. And you are right about painful. I'm guessing this would be a horrid idea in a super large document just based on resource usage alone, much less the tricks required to update. But it gives me something to think about - mostly, that we will probably continue to skirt this insane requirement as best we can. I'm thinking you deserve the bounty just from this sample.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this
[posted example document](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=4DE3A20A33EEA203!1284&app=Word)
as a solution, entailing a rather painful use of SEQ fields.

The document contains its own documentation with examples. It says:

> This document shows one way that you can use field codes in Word to
>   display simple messages along the lines of “Section N continued from
>   previous page” and “…Section N continues on next page” in the document
>   footer and header, as required, where “N” is a section number. In this
>   example, we are getting the Section numbers from the heading numbering
>   of Heading 1 paragraphs. There are other possibilities.
>
> This approach was constructed from an earlier attempt to do Table
>   continuations, and could probably be simplified in various ways.
>
> As it stands, the approach requires
>
> - continuous page numbering – it might work in some section-page numbering scenarios, but probably only by accident. Dealing with two
>     or more numbering schemes per document using field codes alone is not
>     trivial, and may not even be possible.
> - users who understand how to use field codes, and understand how this particular solution works. In this case, in addition to having an
>     understanding of how field codes work in general, they will also need
>     to ensure that each "section" starts with a certain set of field
>     codes, and each "section" also needs to end with a certain set of
>     field codes.